# create-react-app application renders in npm start, but shows only react-empty: 1 in npm build

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I have a React app I've build using `create-react-app`, which uses `react-router`. When I open the test development view using `npm start`, everything works perfectly fine. However, when I build the app -- regardless of what I set the `homepage` field in `package.json` to -- all I get is a #root div with a `react-empty: 1` comment.

My `index.js` component looks like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    (<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
             <IndexRoute component={Home} />
             <Route path="/news" component={News} />
             <Route path="/current" component={Current} />
             <Route path="/previous" component={Previous} />
             <Route path="/about" component={About} />
             <Route path="/enter" component={Enter} />
             <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
             <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Route>
     </Router>),
     document.querySelector('#root')
 );
```

Please let me know if you need to see any more code in order to figure out what's going on. Just to reiterate -- there are no errors showing up whatsoever, either in `npm test` or the build copy of the app.

Comment: What do you mean by "`homepage` field in `package.json`"? Why you added such a field?

Comment: @kbariotis Because that's how `create-react-app` works with regards to assets stored at relative paths. Are you familar with the technology I'm talking about?

Comment: @kbariotis as per documentation: By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:

`"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath"`

This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in the generated HTML file.

Comment: I see, but i don't see how that could affect your app. Any other modification you did?

Comment: Because if it's not set correctly it won't be able to find the script bundle, which means no react app. And no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with relative path as `homepage` in `package.json` and definition of routes.

`Router` will render something like `<!-- react-empty: 1 -->` if it has to render say `null`.

You've set set `Route path="/"` where this should match the relative path in homepage.

You could change this to

```
<Route path=process.env.PUBLIC_URL component={App}>
```

This would take what you've given as homepage in `package.json`